# How to have 2 %s's in python (mysql?)

Tags: python, mysql

got a little problem here with python i'd like some help with.
Here is the issue:
In my code, i got more than 1 variables in my mysql function. One is to determine what username to choose, and other is to put balance. (see code if you dont understand what i mean)

```
    import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="root",
passwd="",
database="J"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
IDE=input("Enter Username")

sql = "UPDATE accounts SET balance = %s WHERE username = %s"

mycursor.execute(sql,(IDE,))


mydb.commit()


print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) affected")
```

How to put a second input "enter balance" and bind it to the balance column instead of username? Tried to do it like:

```
IDE=input("Enter Username")
    IDEBAL=input("enter balance")
    sql = "UPDATE accounts SET balance = %s WHERE username = %s"

    mycursor.execute(sql,(IDE,),(IDEBAL,))
```

But it threw and error at me :(. So how to do it? I know may sound like a very simple question, but hey everyone gotta start somewhere right?

Comment: Well, here's a hint: when you write `(IDE,)`, what do you think the comma and parentheses are for?

Comment: The 2nd parameter to `execute` should be a tuple with the values to replace.

Comment: Also: when you see an error message, your first reaction should not be ":(", but to *read it*. Second, if you don't understand it, is to provide the complete error message to others when you ask them for help.

Comment: `(IDE, IDEBAL)`

Comment: okay so: Did it like (ide, idebal), but now it doesnt even affect any records... Will continue troubleshooting